# Commerce search results using multiist selection

Tags: sxa, content-search, sitecore-commerce, search-facet, sxa-search

We are migrating from Sitecore 8 to Sitecore 9. In Sitecore 8, we have a Multilist which has few values like **Pending, Sold, Available or Not Available**. When any value is selected, for-example if Sold is selected then the list result will contain the result where status = Sold

[image: filter]

Can we do something similar in **Commerce Search Result rendering**? I know we can use search filters to filter the commerce search results but I need something similar to the Multilist. The sellable item has a field Status and its value can be **Pending, Sold, Available or Not Available**. So in the Multilist if the Sold and Pending are selected then Commerce Search Result should only show the results where **Status=Pending or Sold**

Has anyone done something similar to this. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you use a checklist filter component and turn multiple selection on?

Comment: no because the content editor need to have a control so that they can select from the multilist what status needs to be shown to the listing result @Gatogordo

Comment: If it is the editor who needs to limit the search results, you can use different search scopes that you define for them.

Comment: can we use facets in the search scopes?

Comment: A facet is a filter to be used by the visitors (it determines the unique terms for a field and returns a count for each of those terms). So no, that is not relevant within a scope - which is actually a query that predefines your search. You can use facets on a search setup that includes a scope though.

Comment: thanks I will try that @Gatogordo